# Find all entire functions which satisfy the following condition

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am trying to determine all entire functions $f$ on the complex plane which satisfy $f(\exp(\sqrt{2}\pi in))=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I observed that the inner function $\exp(\sqrt{2}\pi in)$ maps $n$ to the boundary of the unit disk. But this does not have to be the case for a random $z\in \mathbb{C}$, so I am not sure if this observation helps.

To break down the problem I distinguished two cases: If $f$ is bounded, then $f$ is obviously constant and $f\equiv 1$ by Liouville's theorem. If $f$ is not bounded, it is either a nonconstant polynomial or a transcendental entire function.
I feel like the identity principle will not be useful here, because the sequence $(\exp(\sqrt{2}\pi in))_n$ does not converge. I also thought about using Casorati Weierstraß' theorem, but could not figure out in which way.

I am looking for just a tiny hint on which theorem could be useful here or which detail to look at, not a complete solution. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *Hint:* The points $\exp(\sqrt{2}\pi in)$ are dense on the unit circle.

Comment: I feel like because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, the sequence $e^{\sqrt{2}\pi i n}$ is dense in the unit circle. So, $f$ is $1$ on the unit circle (by continuity).

Comment: Density does not matter much here, the point is the sequence is infinite and bounded. I mean if a analytic function is constant on such set it must be constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $A = \{ \exp(\sqrt{2}\pi in) \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ is an infinite subset of the (compact) unit circle, and therefore has an accumulation point. Therefore $\{ z \in \Bbb C \mid f(z) = 1 \} \supset A$ has an accumulation point in $\Bbb C$, and the identity theorem can be applied.

Comment: From this I can deduce $f \equiv 1$ on the boundary of the unit circle. By the Cauchy integral formula I obtain $f \equiv 1$ on the entire closed disk $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Now I must only show that $f$ can assume no other value in $\mathbb{C}- \overline{ \mathbb{D}}$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @convergence: It is much simpler. Look at the identity theorem, and compare $f(z)$ with $g(z) = 1$.

Comment: So I can choose a random convergent sequence $(z_k)_k \subset \partial \mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{C}$.  Then always $f(z_k)=1=g(z_k)$, so by the identity theorem, $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @convergence: Is it clearer now?

Comment: If my reasoning in my last comment is sound, than I think so, thank you! It's fascinating, I didn't expect the identity theorem to be so strong.

Comment: @convergence: Yes, in this particular case you could use the continuity first to conclude that $f(z)=1$ on the whole unit circle. But that is not needed because (as you say) the identity theorem is quite strong.